# Javascript inheritance and function overriding

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

```
// Base state class -------------------------
function StateConstuctor()
{

}

// Inherited learn class --------------------
function StateLearnConstructor()
{

}

// Inherited exam class ---------------------
function StateExamConstructor()
{

}


function extend(Child, Parent)
{
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype
    Child.prototype = new F()
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype
}


function createState(rollType)
{
    if (rollType == 'learn')
    {
        extend(StateLearnConstructor, StateConstuctor);
        var state = new StateLearnConstructor();

        return state;
    }
    else if (rollType == 'exam')
    {
        extend(StateExamConstructor, StateConstuctor);
        var state = new StateExamConstructor();

        return state;
    }
}

StateConstuctor.prototype.getTitles = function()
{
   console.log('base "virtual" function');
}
StateLearnConstructor.prototype.getTitles = function()
{
   console.log('learn');
}
StateExamConstructor.prototype.getTitles = function()
{
   console.log('exam');
}
```

Hello, I have the following "OOP" structure and I want to emulate something like virtual functions in C++. So I have base virtual function in `StateConstructor` and different realizations for each subclass.

```
var state = createState('exam');
state.getTitles();
```

But this code calls `StateConstructor` base virtual function. What's wrong here?

Comment: `StateConstuctor` is not called. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkyd58Ly/)

Comment: @Oriol - Isn't that the point though? The mixed inheritance sets the prototype of StateConstructor to state, but the constructor that gets called is the exam constructor as shown in the code.

Comment: @TravisJ Not sure how it is supposed to work, but OP says "*this code calls `StateConstructor`*". And I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @Oriol No, OP said "this code calls StateConstructor base virtual function". In other words "this code calls the base virtual function on `StateConstructor`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createState()` is overwriting the `prototype`s for your `StateLearnConstructor` and your `StateExamConstructor` after you have assigned functions to them.

You shouldn't be conditionally extending them. Just extend them:

```
extend(StateLearnConstructor, StateConstuctor);
extend(StateExamConstructor, StateConstuctor);

StateConstuctor.prototype.getTitles = function () {
    console.log('base "virtual" function');
};
StateLearnConstructor.prototype.getTitles = function () {
    console.log('learn');
};
StateExamConstructor.prototype.getTitles = function () {
    console.log('exam');
};

function createState(rollType) {
    if (rollType == 'learn') {
        return new StateLearnConstructor();
    } else if (rollType == 'exam') {
        return new StateExamConstructor();
    }
}
```

Once you do that, your "virtual functions" should work as expected.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0L6nmh6/)

**Note:** Your implementation for `extend()` is more complicated than it needs to be. The modern way to inherit a prototype is to use `Object.create()`:

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
}
```